# How to add the request info in raven java with logback?

Tags: sentry, raven

We are using raven with logback in java and sentry for error reporting. We can successfully log errors but how can we add the request info?

I have not found any example on https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/java/modules/logback/

Answer (score 0):

You can use MDC or marker in slf4j, here's the link of example from sentry: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/java/modules/logback/. Please check Mapped Tags.
You can specify MDC keys to send as tags instead of including them in Additional Data. This allows them to be filtered within Sentry.